# Using iWeb to create my site but mobile redirect is not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, user-agent, iweb

Using iWeb to create my site: `www.nickvdesign.com`, but mobile redirect to `www.nickvdesign.com/MobileHome.html` is not working

Can anyone suggest/give me some good code to automatically redirect mobile users to my mobile site? It can be in either Javascript with UserAgent or HTML5, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to look at using some javascript like this which will make all devices with small screen resolution view your mobile page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "www.nickvdesign.com/MobileHome.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```